# sending data to database from Angular Application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular5, angular6

I am a Angular developer , I want to send data to database or any place where I can store data 
As I am a frontEnd Developer so I don't know any server side Language ,

How I can store data without using service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use something like firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0